# How to test if a URL exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to test the response code I get by visiting the URL. Some of the URLs won't exist, and I want to get a 404 (`url not available`) or whatever code for them. How can I accomplish this?

Here's the code I tried:

```
require 'net/http'
url = URI.parse("http://www.someurl.lc/")
req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
res = req.request_head(url.path)
puts res.code
```

When I use the above code, [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb), or other similar gems that use [Class: Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html), I get an error: `'initialize': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)` when I try to visit a URL that doesn't exist, which defeats the purpose of he test.

Comment: I think you can get 404 response only if the server exists (but does not provide that page). Afterall 404 is a response. If the server at the URL is missing, you will not get any response, not even 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just put your code in a `begin rescue` block like this:

```
  begin
    url = URI.parse("http://www.someurl.lc/")
    req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    res = req.request_head(url.path)
    puts res.code
  rescue => e
    puts "Exception: #{e}"
    # do the next thing
  end
```

#### Update

You should not rescue all the standard errors. You can rescue specific errors like this:

```
  begin
    url = URI.parse("http://www.someurl.lc/")
    req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    res = req.request_head(url.path)
    puts res.code
  rescue SocketError => e
    puts "Exception: #{e}"
    # do the next thing
  end
```

You should start with only rescuing `SocketError`, and keep adding other error classes if any as sawa mentioned in the comment.

Comment: `rescue` is one way to go, but you should not rescue all standard errors. You should start with only rescuing `SocketError`, and keep adding other error classes if any.

Comment: @sawa yes, that's right. First time, I just gave the idea that he can rescue from such exception like that. I know rescuing everything is not a good practice. Thanks for mentioning. I updated my answer.